# Prove that Log is defined on D

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, logarithms

$D=D(0,R)$ is the disk of center $0$ and radius $R$.
Given that $a>R$ and $\Phi(z)=\frac{a-z}{a+z}$, I have proved that $\forall z\in D$, $\operatorname*{Re}(\Phi(z))>0$.

> Prove that $f = \operatorname{Log}(\Phi)$ is defined and continuous on $D$, where $\operatorname*{Log}$ is the principal branch of log.

Comment: If we examine the case $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $z=\frac{2}{3}$, note that $\Phi(z) = \frac{-1/6}{7/6} = -\frac{1}{7}$, in contradiction to what you've shown. Is everything as you intended with the statement of the problem?

Comment: @JonathanY. I have edited the question , i have added that a>R , know what I have proved is satisfied

Comment: And... your ideas on this are?

Comment: @Did  Im(phi)=0 , then Log(phi)=ln|(a-z)/(a+z)| then can I deduce that it is well defined ?

Comment: And also it becomes continuous as a real logarithmic function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have shown the Möbius transformation $\Phi$ maps $D$ onto some domain $D'$ contained in the right half-plane. Since the principal value ${\rm Log}$ is defined in a certain domain $\Omega$ containing this half-plane it is **obvious** that $f:={\rm Log}\circ\Phi$ is well defined, continuous, and even analytic on $D$.